# How to pass an interval in Setparameter of CreatequeryBuilder (symfony)

Tags: symfony, intervals, query-builder

Using createqueryBuilder , in it's  Setparameter  I want to pass  an interval not just a variable or  a number .I want to pass an interval  like [$min,$max] and where min and max are variable not numbers . here's what I did so far :

```
 $queryBuilder = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:Annonce')->createQueryBuilder('bp')

        ->where('bp.categorie =:cat1' )
        ->setParameter('cat1',[$min,$max])
```

but it is not working and it's not valid code  . Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do either...**

If you want to use `BETWEEN` f.e:

```
$qb->where('bp.categorie BETWEEN :minValue AND :maxValue')
   ->setParameter('minValue', $min)
   ->setParameter('maxValue', $max)
```

And Also You can:

```
$qb->where('bp.categorie >= :minValue')
       ->andWhere('bp.categorie <= :maxValue')
       ->setParameter('minValue', $min)
       ->setParameter('maxValue', $max)
```

Comment: Thank you so much u saved me much time

Answer (score 0):

Also You can use the Expr helper class as follows:

`$qb->where( $qb->expr()->between('bp.categorie', ':minVal', ':maxVal'))
    ->setParameter('minVal', $min)
    ->setParameter('maxVal', $max)`

In such construction You can pass parameters directly to between() method:

`$qb->expr()->between('bp.categorie', $min, $max)`

Comment: Thanks that helped me :D